# Template and inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

If I have a base class and its hierarchy :

```
class BaseClass {
}

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {
}
```

And a templated class :

```
template <class T> struct TemplatedClass {
}
```

How can I achieve this ? :

```
// 1:
void doSomething(TemplatedClass<BaseClass *> const &t);

// 2:
std::vector<TemplatedClass<BaseClass *>> v;

TemplatedClass<DerivedClass *> a;

// Doesn't compile
doSomething(a);

// Doesn't compile
v.push_back(a);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `TemplatedClass<DerivedClass*>` convertable to `TemplatedClass<BaseClass *>`, as they are independent types. Best way would be to have constructor, something like this:

```
template <class T> struct TemplatedClass {
    template<class P> TemplatedClass( const TemplatedClass<P> &an );
};
```

Looks like you are trying to make something like smart pointer, you should look how it is already done on `std::shared_ptr` or `boost::shared_ptr`.
If you plan to use this code in production and/or share it with your team you may want to put additional checks on data type passed to this ctor:

```
template <class T> struct TemplatedClass {
    template<class P, class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<P, T>{}>::type>
    TemplatedClass( const TemplatedClass<P> &an );
};
```

Again best way would be to look into sources of `shared_ptr` and see how it is done there.

Comment: I'd add either a `static_assert(std::is_convertible<P, T>{}, "...");` or a SFINAE-check `template<class P, class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<P, T>{}>::type> TemplatedClass( const TemplatedClass<P> &an );`

Comment: @Dyp thanks, but that can be covered by advise to look into `shared_ptr` :)

Answer (score 2):

You could have your templated classes have a hierarchy, too. You'll need to specify the bases, however:

```
template <typename...>
struct TC;

template <>
struct TC<> {
    virtual ~TC() {}
};
template <typename T, typename... B>
struct TC
    : TC<B...> {
    // ...
};
```

With the variadic argument for the inheritance this should allow you specifying the relationship between the templates to mimick the inheritance hierarchy of the underlying. For example:

```
TC<Base>* d = new TC<Derived, Base>(/*...*/);
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could provide `Base` intrusively via a typedef in `Derived`.

Comment: Thanks, it's a great way but I can't apply this method in my case.